# fgets error message loop -Linux shell in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, fgets

Trying to build a linux shell everything works great except this one error message at the top!

i set LINE=81, and it prints out the error message total length/LINE times. im having trouble finding a way to fix that. I think it's because it keeps looping and since itll always have that condition itll print. and I dont want it to terminate, just refresh and keep inputting, any ideas? I am required ot provide an error message.

edit:when adding the '\n' it still functions the same.

```
char commands[LINE];

while (fgets(commands, LINE, stdin)!= NULL) {

    if (strlen(commands) >= LINE - 1) {
        printf("Too Many arguments please enter %d characters\n",LINE-2);
        continue;
    }

    childPID = fork();

    if (childPID < 0) {

        perror("fork");

        exit(-1);
    }
    if (childPID == 0) {
        parse(commands);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        if (waitpid(childPID, &status, 0) !=childPID) {
            perror("waitpid");
        } else
            if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
                printf("Exited Abnormally\n");
            }

        putc('\n', stdout);
        fputs(PROMPT,stdout);

    }

    commands[0] = '\0';

 }
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You should use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) -or, in an interactive program, [readline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)- and compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`)

Comment: What is the error you got.

Comment: That `strlen` check inside the loop is not needed, [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) never writes more than `LINE` characters (in your case) to the buffer provided, including possible newline and terminator.

Comment: i am required to provide and error message.... its dumb

Comment: What's dumb in that. You are posting code saying fgets error. I want to know what's that error?? If that's what you call dumb, then smart guy must tell what's the error.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Too many arguments" error message that your program prints?

Comment: yes the "too many arguments" sorry if i didn't clarify. Its not an error im getting but an error im printing

Comment: Note that error messages should be printed on 'standard error' because it is the standard place to write error messages.  Standard output should be reserved for non-error output.

Answer (score 2):

You should put `\n` at the end of the error message:

```
printf("Too Many arguments please enter %d characters\n",LINE-2);
```

`stdout` is normally line-buffered, so the buffer isn't flushed until you print a newline. When your program forks, the buffer is copied into the child. When the child calls `exit()`, it flushes its copy of the buffer. And when the parent calls `putc('\n')` it flushes its copy. As a result, the message is printed twice.

Comment: Alternatively, call `fflush`

Comment: That would work, too, although it leaves the user in the middle of the line. It's usually better to start a newline after a message.

Comment: So if I only want it to print once...I cant?  because the child will flush it again? It seems like it prints the message many times depending on the amount the user inputs

Comment: But if you flush it first in the parent, either by printing a newline or calling `fflush`, there's no copy in the child.

Answer (score 0):

so turned out I needed to iterate through and then print and move my prompt accordingly

```
    while (fgets(commands, LINE, stdin)!= NULL) {

    if (strlen(commands) > LINE-2) {

       fprintf(stderr,"Too many chars\n");

      while (getchar() != '\n' && !feof(stdin));


    }
   else
    {


    childPID = fork();

    if (childPID < 0) {

        perror("fork");

        exit(-1);
    }
    if (childPID == 0) {

        parse(commands);

        exit(0);
    } else {

        if (waitpid(childPID, &status, 0) !=childPID) {
            perror("waitpid is not responding");
        } else
            if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Unusually exit\n");
        }

        //putc('\n', stdout);
        //fputs(PROMPT,stdout);


    }


    }
    putc('\n', stdout);
   fputs(PROMPT,stdout); 
}
exit(0);
```

}